# stacked chart with ZingChart

Tags: javascript, charts, stacked-chart, zingchart

I'm making stacked bar chart with ZingChart library.
Here is a sample  http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/
but suppose i need a limit , e.g the color should only change if it exceeds 15k. Is that possible?

```js
var myConfig = 
        {
            "type": "bar",
            "stacked": true,
            "stack-type": "normal",
            "background-color": "#FFFFFF",
            "title": {
                "text": "Mobile OS Sales  - ",
                "font-family": "arial",
                "x": "40px",
                "y": "5px",
                "align": "left",
                "bold": false,
                "font-size": "16px",
                "font-color": "#000000",
                "background-color": "none"
            },
            "subtitle": {
                "text": "<i>Since January 14, 2013</i>",
                "font-family": "arial",
                "x": "175px",
                "y": "5px",
                "align": "left",
                "bold": false,
                "font-size": "16px",
                "font-color": "#7E7E7E",
                "background-color": "none"
            },
            "plot": {
                "bar-width": "25px",
                "hover-state": {
                    "visible": false
                }
            },
            "labels":[
                {
                    "text": "11,245 Android",
                    "background-color": "#90A23B",
                    "font-size": "14px",
                    "font-family": "arial",
                    "font-weight": "normal",
                    "font-color": "#FFFFFF",
                    "padding": "10%",
                    "border-radius": "3px",
                    "offset-y":-30,
                    "shadow": false,
                    "callout": true,
                    "callout-height": "10px",
                    "callout-width": "15px",
                    "hook":"node:plot=2;index=4"
                },
                {
                    "text": "9,750 iOS",
                    "background-color": "#787878",
                    "font-size": "14px",
                    "font-family": "arial",
                    "font-weight": "normal",
                    "font-color": "#FFFFFF",
                    "padding": "10%",
                    "border-radius": "3px",
                    "shadow": false,
                    "callout": true,
                    "callout-height": "10px",
                    "callout-width": "15px",
                    "hook":"node:plot=2;index=5",
                    "offset-y": -30
                },
                {
                    "text": "15,279 Windows",
                    "thousands-separator": ",",
                    "background-color": "#FFC700",
                    "font-size": "14px",
                    "font-family": "arial",
                    "font-weight": "normal",
                    "font-color": "#FFFFFF",
                    "padding": "10%",
                    "border-radius": "3px",
                    "shadow": false,
                    "callout": true,
                    "callout-height": "10px",
                    "callout-width": "15px",
                    "offset-y": -30,
                    "hook":"node:plot=2;index=9"
                }
            ],
            "scale-x": {
                "values": [
                    "JAN",
                    "FEB",
                    "MAR",
                    "APR",
                    "MAY",
                    "JUN",
                    "JUL",
                    "AUG",
                    "SEP",
                    "OCT",
                    "NOV",
                    "DEC"
                ],
                "line-color": "#7E7E7E",
                "tick": {
                    "visible": false
                },
                "guide": {
                    "visible": false
                },
                "item": {
                    "font-family": "arial",
                    "font-color": "#8B8B8B"
                }
            },
            "scale-y": {
                "values": "0:70000:10000",
                "short": true,
                "line-color": "#7E7E7E",
                "tick": {
                    "visible": false
                },
                "guide": {
                    "line-style": "solid"
                },
                "item": {
                    "font-family": "arial",
                    "font-color": "#8B8B8B"
                }
            },
            "series": [
                {
                    "values": [
                        15000,
                        12000,
                        42000,
                        13000,
                        19500,
                        9750,
                        11500,
                        36500,
                        11750,
                        16000,
                        9800,
                        43279
                    ],
                    "background-color": "#787878"
                },
                {
                    "values": [
                        13000,
                        8000,
                        5000,
                        20000,
                        17000,
                        10000,
                        34000,
                        6000,
                        5500,
                        15279,
                        1500,
                        2250
                    ],
                    "background-color": "#FFC700"
                },
                {
                    "values": [
                        17000,
                        9000,
                        2000,
                        12500,
                        11245,
                        1750,
                        5500,
                        3000,
                        10000,
                        9750,
                        1500,
                        17750
                    ],
                    "background-color": "#90A23B"
                }
            ],
            "tooltip": {
                "visible": false
            }
        }
;

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 500, 
 width: 725 
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= 'https://cdn.zingchart.com/2.1.1/zingchart.min.js'></script>
  <script> zingchart.MODULESDIR = 'https://cdn.zingchart.com/2.1.1/modules/';
  ZC.LICENSE = ['569d52cefae586f634c54f86dc99e6a9','ee6b7db5b51705a13dc2339db3edaf6d'];</script>
 
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Sample Data :
Date    Limit   Total   Normal  Excess 
14-Jul  200      170    170     0
14-Aug  200      100    100     0
14-Sep  200      200    200     0
14-Oct  200      280    200     80
14-Nov  200      300    200     100
14-Dec  200      310    200     110
15-Jan  200      330    200     130
15-Feb  200      340    200     140
15-Mar  400      380    380       0
15-Apr  400      390    390       0
15-May  400      420    400      20
15-Jun  400      440    400      40
15-Jul  400      460    400      60
15-Aug  400      480    400      80
15-Sep  400      500    400     100
15-Oct  400      520    400     120
15-Nov  400      540    400     140
15-Dec  400      560    400     160
16-Jan  400      580    400     180

[Sample data](http://ideone.com/hzZOJ2)

Comment: Hey there! ZingChart team member here. Just need some clarification to answer your question. Is your data one big series that just needs to show differences in colors by value? Or do you have multiple series?

Comment: Actually I'm reading data from CSV, so still have doubts how should i approach this ?

Comment: I answered your other question with a CSV demo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31884356/1357573

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I think this might be what you're looking for. Feel free to let me know if not.*

This demo assumes that you start with one array of totals like this:

```
var origSeries = [10316,23988,39643,40708,9857,18558,42194,28130,26569,23148,31424,41053,27838,38383,36105,47613,35903,40775,37769,24143];
```

We'll programmatically split these into two series: one that is below threshold and one that is above. Then we set the desired background color on each series.

Run the snippet to see it in action. Remember, you could do this an infinite number of times to create additional stacks using different thresholds.

Again, I'm on the ZC team so don't hesitate to reach out for help!

```js
var origSeries = [10316, 23988, 39643, 40708, 9857, 18558, 42194, 28130, 26569, 23148, 31424, 41053, 27838, 38383, 36105, 47613, 35903, 40775, 37769, 24143];
var series1 = [];
var series2 = [];

function calcThreshold(array, threshold) {
  var difference;
  array.forEach(function(el, index, array) {
    difference = el - threshold;
    if (difference <= 0) {
      series1.push(el);
      series2.push(null);
    } else {
      series1.push(threshold);
      series2.push(difference);
    }
  });
}

calcThreshold(origSeries, 15000);

var myConfig = {
  "type": "bar",
  "stacked": true,
  "stack-type": "normal",
  "background-color": "#FFFFFF",
  "title": {
    "text": "Mobile OS Sales  - ",
    "font-family": "arial",
    "x": "40px",
    "y": "5px",
    "align": "left",
    "bold": false,
    "font-size": "16px",
    "font-color": "#000000",
    "background-color": "none"
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": "<i>Since January 14, 2013</i>",
    "font-family": "arial",
    "x": "175px",
    "y": "5px",
    "align": "left",
    "bold": false,
    "font-size": "16px",
    "font-color": "#7E7E7E",
    "background-color": "none"
  },
  "plot": {
    "bar-width": "25px",
    "hover-state": {
      "visible": false
    }
  },
  "scale-x": {
    "values": [
      "JAN",
      "FEB",
      "MAR",
      "APR",
      "MAY",
      "JUN",
      "JUL",
      "AUG",
      "SEP",
      "OCT",
      "NOV",
      "DEC"
    ],
    "line-color": "#7E7E7E",
    "tick": {
      "visible": false
    },
    "guide": {
      "visible": false
    },
    "item": {
      "font-family": "arial",
      "font-color": "#8B8B8B"
    }
  },
  "scale-y": {
    "values": "0:70000:10000",
    "short": true,
    "line-color": "#7E7E7E",
    "tick": {
      "visible": false
    },
    "guide": {
      "line-style": "solid"
    },
    "item": {
      "font-family": "arial",
      "font-color": "#8B8B8B"
    }
  },
  "series": [{
    "values": series1,
    "background-color": "#787878"
  }, {
    "values": series2,
    "background-color": "#ff4900"
  }],
  "tooltip": {
    "visible": false
  }
};

zingchart.render({
  id: 'myChart',
  data: myConfig,
  height: 500,
  width: 725
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
<div id="myChart"></div>
```

Comment: Hey If I'm getting data from csv file , How should I manipulate that in two different series.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to include sample data so I can see what format you're working with? I'd be happy to update the demo for you.