# Getting series and values from CSV data in Zingchart

Tags: charts, bar-chart, linechart, zingchart

[image: Graph should look like this.]While creating mixed chart in Zingchart we can pass the type attribute values with values array. But I'm not sure when reading data from CSV how this can be achieved.
I want to create mixed chart as on fiddle link below but data is to be read from a csv file.

```js
  var myConfig = 
      {
      "type":"mixed",
      "series":[
        {
          "values":[51,53,47,60,48,52,75,52,55,47,60,48],
          "type":"bar",
          "hover-state":{
            "visible":0
          }
        },
        {
          "values":[69,68,54,48,70,74,98,70,72,68,49,69],
          "type":"line"
        }
      ]
    }
  zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 500, 
 width: 725 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
<div id="myChart"></div>
```

Comment: Are you using the same data set that you provided in your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722559/stacked-chart-with-zingchart If so, which column of would you use for your line chart?

Comment: i will use second column for line chart.

Comment: I want first column at x-axis for that i will use vertical labels but with stacked chart line doesn't come as in sample graph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I put together a demo for you using the sample data you provided in [one of your related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722559/stacked-chart-with-zingchart). If you go to [this demo page](http://www.zingchart.com/support/csvParse) and upload the CSV you originally provided, you should get this chart:[image: ZingChart mixed chart from CSV]

ZingChart includes a CSV parser for basic charts, but a more complex case like this requires a bit of preprocessing to get your data where it needs to be. I used [PapaParse](http://papaparse.com/) for this demo, but there are other parsing libraries available.

Here's the JavaScript. I'm using a simple file input in the HTML to get the CSV.

```
var csvData;
var limit = [],
    normal = [],
    excess = [],
    dates = [];
var myConfig = {
    theme: "none",
    "type": "mixed",
    "scale-x": {
        "items-overlap":true,
        "max-items":9999,
        values: dates,
        guide: {
            visible: 0
        },
        item:{
            angle:45    
        } 
    },
    "series": [{
        "type": "bar",
        "values": normal,
        "stacked": true,
        "background-color": "#4372C1",
        "hover-state": {
            "visible": 0
        }
    }, {
        "type": "bar",
        "values": excess,
        "stacked": true,
        "background-color": "#EB7D33",
        "hover-state": {
            "visible": 0
        }
    }, {
        "type": "line",
        "values": limit
    }]
};

/* Get the file and parse with PapaParse */
function parseFile(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    Papa.parse(file, {
        delimiter: ",",
        complete: function(results) {
            results.data.shift(); //the first array is header values, we don't need these
            csvData = results.data;
            prepChart(csvData);
        }
    });
}

/* Process the results from the PapaParse(d) CSV and populate 
 ** the arrays for each chart series and scale-x values
 */
function prepChart(data) {
    var excessVal;

    //PapaParse data is in a 2d array
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        //save reference to your excess value
        //cast all numeric values to int (they're originally strings)
        var excessVal = parseInt(data[i][4]);

        //date, limit value, and normal value can all be pushed to their arrays
        dates.push(data[i][0]);
        limit.push(parseInt(data[i][1]));
        normal.push(parseInt(data[i][3]));

        /* we must push a null value into the excess
        ** series if there is no excess for this node
        */
        if (excessVal == 0) {
            excess.push(null);
        } else {
            excess.push(excessVal);
        }
    }
    //render your chart
    zingchart.render({
        id: 'myChart',
        data: myConfig,
        height: 500,
        width: 725
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#csv-file').change(parseFile);
});
```